# How to use Kustomize to add same sidecar container to both Deployment and CronJob

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I have both `Deployment` and `CrobJob` and I'd like to append the same sidecar container to them. However, the path to the `containers` list in `Deployment` and `CronJob` is different. I had to create 2 patch files and copy/paste the same sidecar container fragment.

#### file sidecar-for-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sidecar-patch-for-deployment
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: sidecar-xyz
          image: ...
          ...
```

#### file sidecar-for-crobjob.yaml

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: sidecar-patch-for-cronjob
spec:
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: sidecar-xyz
              image: ...
              ...
```

Then in the `kustomize.yaml`

```
kind: Kustomization
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
resources:
  - base

patches:
  - target:
      kind: Deployment
      labelSelector: "require-sidecar=true"
    path: sidecar-for-deployment.yaml

  - target:
      kind: CronJob
      labelSelector: "require-sidecar=true"
    path: sidecar-for-crobjob.yaml
```

That works, but I have to copy/paste a big chunk of the sidecar container code in 2 places. How can I avoid that duplication?

Another point, when I did like above, the sidecar container is prepended in the container list, how can I have it appended instead?

Comment: You're going to require two separate patches in this situation because a Deployment and a CronJob have different structure; the same patch cannot apply to both resource types.

Comment: @larsks yes, I'm doing like that. I want to avoid repeating the same block of the sidecar container declaration, which is quite long, in 2 patches. With helm, I can easily do it with a template function. Is there away in kustomize?